# DNN network architecture of the original parent network from which the Intel OpenVINO pre-trained models were optimized and if yes, how?

Tags: openvino

I have used pre-trained models from OpenVINO for inference. I would like to know how to see the network structure of these models? And if I want to re-train these networks from scratch, can I know from which parent models these pre-trained models were originally derived from?

Answer (score 0):

- Information about Intel pre-trained models is available at the following page, “Overview of OpenVINO™ Toolkit Intel's Pre-Trained Models”.
  https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2020.4/omz_models_intel_index.html
- Information about public pre-trained models is available at the following page, “Overview of OpenVINO™ Toolkit Public Models”.
  https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2020.4/omz_models_public_index.html
- DL Workbench can be used to visualize the network structure. DL Workbench is a web-based graphical environment that enables users to visualize, fine-tune, and compare performance of deep learning models. More information about DL Workbench is available at the following page, “Introduction to Deep Learning Workbench”.
  https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2020.4/workbench_docs_Workbench_DG_Introduction.html

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, I would like to know the network structure of the parent models (from which the pretrained models were optimized) in order to re-train them on my own data. I don't find this information in any of the links you provided. I have re-worded the title so this is is more clear.